# Continuity of piecewise function of multiple variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have to find a function $g(x)$ such that $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2}$, with $f(x,y)$ defined below :
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x + y}, & x \neq -y \\
\\
      g(x), & x = -y 
\end{cases}$$

To find $g(x)$, I've tried to find the limit as
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x, -x)} f(x,y)$$

But at this point, I really don't know what I'm doing, I can't find a logical way out of this. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{x^2-y^2}{x+y}=\frac{(x-y)\color{green}{(x+y)}}{\color{green}{x+y}}$$

Comment: My God...Thank you so much, I can't believe I overlooked this. Really grateful, I've given me a headache for the last thirty minutes!

Comment: @shlogek It that answers your question, don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick sign below the "downvote" button.